# Incorrect syntax near '+=' SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

Im try to add value to my declared variable, I'm just newbie hopefully you can give me the general idea for this one. thanks

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testsp] 
@y int =0,

Select 

            case when column1 <> ''
            then
            @y+=1 -  Add value to y

                '0'+ @y -  display current value of y
            end 

From table
```

Comment: @y = @y+1 incorrect syntax on =

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why the `case` ? If you want to count rows that aren't empty, why aren't you using `SELECT COUNT(*) from table where Column1<>''` ?

Comment: You can either increment `@y` (`SELECT @y += (CASE WHEN ...)`) or select the current value of `@y`, but not both in one query. Use an `IF` instead.

Comment: There's a lot more wrong with that query that just the `+=`. You have strings in what appears to be an equation (should these be comments?) and you're trying to take away that string from parts of your equation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos its just a short version... the query is quite too long. but the main idea im try to fix is how to add value to @y in a case

Comment: @user3751759 short version of *what*? This looks like an attempt to convert loops into SQL, if not an entire script. Most likely the entire query can be converted to a simple SELECT

Comment: @Larnu.. yes a lot is quite wrong...its just a only a part of a very long query.. but the main idea im trying to found out is how to add value to @y and display it after adding value

Comment: I think that the syntax error comes from the `-` sign - a remark in SQL Server is `--`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos its not a loop.. it just will tell.. if column1 <> '' then @y will add 1 value and its value will be displayed as a result..

Comment: @user3751759 that main idea is 100% wrong. You don't need a variable to count anything, you can't do that in the *SELECT* statement anyway, you can't use the *parameter* for that because nobody will ever see it. Explain what you actually want, not how you think it should be done

Comment: @user3751759 that should be in a WHERE statement, not an IF or CASE. You aren't displaying anything to anyone with that code either. I already posted how you can get that count - `SELECT COUNT(*) from table where Column1<>''`. You can use this in a subquery. You can format the result as a string, although that should be the job of the client program.

Comment: Your SQL code doesn't make sense at all. Please [edit] your question to include an explanation of what you want the code to do, some sample data as DDL+DML and desired results.

Comment: As @ZoharPeled said, if this is part of a much bigger query, you're probably going to need to provide DDL and Sample Data (in a comsumable format [How to post a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)) and discribe your goal/expected result set, to get an answer that's going to help you here.

Comment: hmmm.. ignore the whole script cause i cant post the whole query here. What im trying to achieve is add value to @y if the column is not null

Comment: Add what value to `@y`? Are you simply wishing to return 1 for if the column has a value of `''` and `0` if it doesn't? you don't need a parameter/variable for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-written your Proc as Below :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testsp] 
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @y INT =0

SELECT 
    @y = --You Can Ignore This Line Since Not neccessary
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(column1,'') <> ''
             THEN @y+1
            ELSE @y END
    FROM [TABLE]
END
```

Comment: Wouldn't this effectively be the same as `SELECT @y = COUNT(CASE column1 WHEN '' THEN 1 END) FROM [Table];`? This removes the use of the self referencing variable.

Comment: @Larnu its more like the adding of value is more flexible i can add 2..or 3..and use again the current value of @y for the next case without resetting its value

Comment: @user3751759 yes, I deleted that comment and added a different one.

Comment: like i said ignore the whole script.. i just need how to add value on @y